# Problems of reshape in R markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I want to create a data set long to wide format.When I run this programme at R console then it gives the output.But it doesn't work at R markdown.

```
   library(gapminder)
   library(dplyr)
   library(knitr)
   dat <- gapminder%>%
  group_by(continent,year) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(lifeExp))
  dat1 <- as.data.frame(dat)
   res <- reshape( dat1 , timevar ="continent" , idvar ="year",  direction = 
  "wide" , v.names="mean")
    kable(res)
```

But when I run this programme at R markdown , it shows the error message : Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , timevar) : undefined columns selected
Calls:  ... reshape -> reshapeWide -> unique -> [ -> [.data.frame
Execution halted

Comment: Can you create a minimal `Rmd` file to reproduce the error? Have you load all the libraries within markdown?

Comment: @drmariod yes, I have loaded all the libraries within markdown. Actually, I don't know How can I make a minimal Rmd file?

Comment: in case you use Studio, say File -> new -> Rmarkdown and delete everything below the `---` line, create a r code chunk and paste your code in it. knit it, and tell if this works.

Comment: @drmariod yap it works when I run this programme after the delete everything below the --- line. But I don't understand why it doesn't work when I run it with everything.

Comment: I guess the problem is somewhere else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does for me with the following simple call:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "2/14/2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Long to wide

Example 
```{r}

library(gapminder)
   library(dplyr)
   library(knitr)
   dat <- gapminder%>%
  group_by(continent,year) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(lifeExp))
  dat1 <- as.data.frame(dat)
   res <- reshape( dat1 , timevar ="continent" , idvar ="year",  direction = 
  "wide" , v.names="mean")
    kable(res)


```
````